# Unable to create multiple threads using for loop

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winapi, for-loop

I am trying to create 3 threads using a for loop. Following is my code snippet:

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc0(LPVOID param)
{
   return 0; 
}
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc1(LPVOID param)
{
    return 0;
}
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc2(LPVOID param)
{
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd )
{
   DWORD threadId = 0;
   int max_number=1;
   //Start the threads
   typedef DWORD (WINAPI * THREADPROCFN)(LPVOID lpParameter);
   THREADPROCFN function[3] = {ThreadProc0,ThreadProc1,ThreadProc2} ;
   for (int i = 0; i < max_number; i++) 
   {
      CreateThread( NULL,
                    0,
                    (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&function[i],
                    (LPVOID) i,
                    0,
                    NULL
                   );
   }
}
```

The code is compiled successfully but when executed, the error is solution.exe has stopped working.
When I Debug the code, I get the following error:

***Unhandled exception at 0x0034fd00 in Solution.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.***

Waiting for help.

Comment: What happens if you change `(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&function[i],` to `(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)function[i],` (i.e. don't take the address of a pointer to a function, take the pointer to the function)

Comment: Note that your problem has nothing to do with creating multiple threads since `max_number` is set to 1 - you're only trying to create one thread.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely want `function[i]` (the `i`th function pointer to a thread start routine) rather than `&function[i]` (a pointer to the `i`th function pointer to a thread start routine).

```
   typedef DWORD (WINAPI * THREADPROCFN)(LPVOID lpParameter);
   THREADPROCFN function[3] = {ThreadProc0,ThreadProc1,ThreadProc2} ;

   for (int i = 0; i < max_number; i++) 
   {
      CreateThread( NULL,
                    0,
                    //                      v Here!
                    (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&function[i],
                    (LPVOID) i,
                    0,
                    NULL
                   );
   }
```

Being less familiar with C++ than I used to be, I *think* that after changing that the cast to `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE` would become redundant.

Comment: Also - get rid of the unnecessary `(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)` cast.  Without the cast, the compiler will give a warning about passing in the wrong type of pointer. The cast prevents the compiler from issuing a warning about the problem - it's effectively telling the compiler, "don't worry, I know what I'm doing even if it doesn't appear to make sense".  If you pass in the correct pointer type, you won't need the cast and the compiler won't complain.